# Android looping through an array of ImageView and calling a function that takes the ImageView as argument

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop

I want to loop through an array of ImageView(s) and call a function for each ImageView and using the ImageView as the argument for the function, and also set a pause for the loop, so that the loop will pause for 3s before calling the function again with the next ImageView. So far this is the closest that I got, but it still showed up error as I am unable to access the array from within the Runnable.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView imageView1, imageView2, imageView3,........ imageView16;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        .
        .
        .

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        // Array of ImageView(s)
        final ImageView[] pieces = {imageView1, imageView2, .....};

        // Looping through ImageView array
        for(int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            Runnable shuffle = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    playLevel(pieces[i]);
                }
            };
            // delay the calling of function so that the loop pause every 3s
            handler.postDelayed(shuffle, 3000);
        }
    }

    public void playLevel(ImageView imageView) {
        // some function
    }
}
```

All suggestions and better way of achieving this are greatly welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the `pieces` variable inside the `Runnable` (because it is `final`), what you won't be able to access is the `i` variable. You can do this:  `final int index = i` and use `index` instead of `i` inside the `run()` method. Also, you may want to increase the delay for each image, otherwise all the operations will be executed almost at the same time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
        final int index = i;
        Runnable shuffle = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                playLevel(pieces[index]);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(shuffle, (i+1)*3000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Great it works now. Have been tweaking with the code for quite some hours now, finally. Can' accept answer for now, it said 3 more mins than I can accept your answer.